# How to perform performSegueWithIdentfier from within UIView

Tags: uiview, uibutton, segue, ibaction

Ok so I have a UIButton embedded into a UIImageView which forms part of a UIView.

The button's selector calls a method which should run:

> [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueToMoreInfo"];

However I get the error:
no visible at interface for 'myclassname' declares the selector 'performSegueWithIdentifier'.

Basically  I really need to perform a segue from within the UIView. If not possible how would I call from the UIViewController instead?

EDIT: MORE INFO:

```
//adding button
UIButton *attractionButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[attractionButton addTarget:self
           action:@selector(buttonClicked:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[attractionButton setTitle:@"Attraction Info" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
attractionButton.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 80, 160.0, 40.0);
[_image1 addSubview:attractionButton];
```

My method :

```
 (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueToMoreInfo" sender:sender];
}
```

Comment: where is that code sitting? In what class? Is that class a subclass of UIViewController?

Comment: It is sitting in a subclass of UIView which I think is why it is not working. I need to know if it is possible to do it from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"aseguename" sender:self];
```

is a UIViewController method. That is why you are getting this error. Also views should not talk to ViewControllers except through protocols.

Having said that, you are going about this the wrong way. IBActions for buttons and other UIView objects should be in the ViewController. So I would move the IBAction to your View Controller and hook it to the button from there. Then insert your code in that IBAction.

Update after the code posted:
All of the code posted should be in your View Controller. I would just change:

```
[_image1 addSubview:attractionButton];
```

to

```
[self.view addSubview:attractionButton];
```

or if you really want that button to be a subview to your image, then you can leave your code, just make sure to create an IBOutlet property for that image, from your image in interface builder to your View Controller and call it _image1.

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok many thanks I was thinking it would be something along this line.